# How I can view, read and edit the source code of a Python Module

Tags: python, module

I have heard that Python Modules are pre-written python program. So I want to read and edit the source code of installed modules so that I can understand other's programs and build my own module later.

I can print the desired module source code, through this method.

```
import random
import inspect
src = inspect.getsource(inspect)
print(src)
```

But this method prints the module's source code in the terminal, I can copy-pest. But is there any way to directly make a separate python file and read and edit the source code of the installed or built-in python modules through this method or any other method?

Comment: Rather than `print(src)` you can write it to a file with `open()`

Comment: see also `random.__file__` and `inspect.__file__` - this gives you path to file with code and you can open in any editor. But when you want to save it then on some systems it may need admin privileges.

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to read edit and view the python built-in module you can use this method to directly open the python file (module) with this method

```
import random
import inspect
src = inspect.getsourcefile(random)
print(src)

Output:
/usr/lib/python3.9/random.py
```

This will display the python module file and its location. If you use VS Code you can directly open the python module with this keyboard shortcut ctrl+click. But remember that editing modules can be harmful. You can copy the file and create a separate file to edit the module. Rather you can read and improve your code. That's all, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's [file__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#file__) attribute

It indicates the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded (if loaded from a file), or the pathname of the shared library file for extension modules loaded dynamically from a shared library. It might be missing for certain types of modules, such as C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter, and the import system may opt to leave it unset if it has no semantic meaning (e.g. a module loaded from a database).

```
import random

print(random.__file__)

Output:
/usr/lib/python3.9/random.py
```

Then you could that open that file.
But directly editing source code of Python's built-in modules is obviously not recommended.